# Where does Firefox saves the logins and passwords?

Tags: firefox

What is the folder where Firefox saves the logins and passwords so it can remember after and the  user just have to type the password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Directory is:

%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\

Within this Directory is a Folder called:

"XXXXXXXX.default" (it's all in there)

The Files are **key3.db** and **signons.sqlite**